# jquery loop and post not working together

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been trying to get this to work for hours now.

I'm trying to get each input with .textinputclass, combine them together and via ajax putting that into a database.

Two tings are working seperate, I can get each input and put those together in the format that i want.

and I can use .post to send data to a php script to put it in the database

```
$(".addSubmit").click(function(){

        $('.textinputclass').each(function(){

            var textData = $(this).val();
            var thisLanguage = $(this).attr('id');
            var textData = '[:' + thisLanguage + ']' + textData;

            languagearray.push(textData);
        }); 

        var nameData = 'test1111';

        var textData = languagearray.join('');
        var languagearray = [];


        var data = {
            'name' : nameData,
            'text' : textData
        };

        $.post('../wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-hardcodedtext/additem.php', data, function() {
            alert('done!');
        });
    });
```

if I remove the .each function and just put text in the data array then the .post works.

Comment: @Elfayer there's no synchronisation needed here - `when` won't help

Comment: Please describe _how it fails_ when the `.each` loop is in place?  The use of `post` is probably a red herring - most likely the loop simply isn't creating the values you think it is.

Comment: Did you check the value of "data" variable just before posting it? Something can be wrong inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the definition of `languagearray`.

Although you have correctly declared it, that declaration is *after* the `.each` loop.

The net result is that the *declaration* (but not the *initialisation*) of `languagearray` is "hoisted" to the top of the function, making it available in the entire scope, but its initial value is just `undefined` instead of `[]`.

As the variable is undefined, you can't call `push` on it, which should have been evident within your browser's JS console.

Comment: Thanks, the array after the loop was supposed to be to clear the array but i forgot to declare it before the loop.

I now declared it before the function and used languagearray.length = 0; to clear it.

Comment: @NickH yes, I guessed that you were trying to erase the array.  However there's actually no need to do so - the garbage collector will get rid of it automatically when it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must create an array `languagearray`.
http://jsfiddle.net/FFr5z/

Edit:

```
var languagearray = [];
$('.textinputclass').each(function(){
    var textData = $(this).val();
    var thisLanguage = $(this).attr('id');
    var textData = '[:' + thisLanguage + ']' + textData;
    languagearray.push(textData);
});
```

Comment: technically the OP did _declare_ the variable `languagearray` - what he failed to do was _initialise_ it do an empty array before trying to use it.